# MultiProcessing or Threading Or Asyncio

Tags: python, parallel-processing, can-bus

My project is to send certain objects detected on the camera with a CAN message to the vehicle as they see it. Basically, I send a message when the camera sees people or animals. I am experiencing 0.5 second camera freezes while sending a message. I know that `time.sleep (0.5)` inside the simple_periodic_send function created this. What I want is to send messages without experiencing these freezes. How can I solve this?

Note: If `time.sleep (0.5)` is not in the function, the message will not be sent.

```
import jetson.inference
import jetson.utils
import time
import os 
import can
from can.interface import Bus
import logging
can.rc['interface']='pcan'
can.rc['channel']='PCAN_USBBUS1'
can.rc['bitrate']=250000
bus=Bus()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
net=jetson.inference.detectNet("ssd-mobilenet-v2",threshold=0.5)
camera=jetson.utils.gstCamera(1280,720,"0")
display=jetson.utils.glDisplay()
def simple_periodic_send(bus,ClassID):
    """sends a message every 200ms with no explicit timeout sleeps for 2 seconds then stops the task"""
    print("starting to send a message every 200ms for 2sc")
    msg=can.Message(arbitration_id=0x18FFA4CF,data=[ClassID,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],extended_id=True)
    task=bus.send_periodic(msg,period=0.05)
    assert isinstance(task,can.CyclicSendTaskABC)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    task.stop()
    print("stopped cyclic send")
    return task

while display.IsOpen():
    img,width,height=camera.CaptureRGBA()
    detections=net.Detect(img,width,height)
    display.RenderOnce(img,width,height)
    display.SetTitle("Object Detection | Network {:.0f} FPS".format(net.GetNetworkFPS()))
    
    for detection in detections:
        if detection.ClassID!=0:
            simple_periodic_send(bus,detection.ClassID)
    simple_periodic_send(bus,0)
```

Comment: Well, what's the sleep supposed to do? The CAN controller in itself will likely be hardware buffered and there's no CAN frame taking 500ms to send. Though I'm assuming this is some manner of Linux goo and there's no real-time performance no matter? Do the real-time math: extended frame with 8 byte data and intermission field = 129 bits. 1/250kbps times 129 bits = 516us. I very much doubt the Linux-something can keep up with that, so why the sleep?

Comment: I don't know the main reason why time.sleep(0.5) is there but when I remove it, I get a lot of non-periodic received message which is unwanted. For example,the function needs to send messages in every 200ms and it does. When I remove the time.sleep, it send messages randomly. Here the source of code: https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/bcm.html
Another comment: Maybe I should use send_one function instead of simple_periodic send. When the camera sees the object then call the send_one function. I will try this. Send_one : https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: How can a function containing a 500ms sleep send out messages every 200ms? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry I forget the change the comment. It should be sends a message every 50ms. Related code is here: task=bus.send_periodic(msg,period=0.05)

Comment: Let me explain more clearly. The message doesn't take 500 ms to send message. It just takes 50ms. The problem is when the camera sees the object, it calls the simple periodic function and at that time the camera freezes for 0.5 seconds. This is incredibly hard on the CPU, but it misses some frames.

Comment: Well, I can't explain why you have a 500ms delay in that function. I doubt the original author of the code can do that either.